# Copy value from same row but other Column (variable offset) Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy

The code below makes sure that only one of the cells in the range("D16:E25") can contain any value, when any value/string is entered in one of the other cell's within this range, the code deletes all the others. (This part works fine, thanks to "Macro Man")

Now I'd like the code to copy(and paste to "B5") a value from a certain cell in Column B, this needs to be the the cell in the same row as the value in the range("D16:E16").
Tried the folowing code you can find below... but it didn't work.
Does annyone knows a sollution for this?
I'd prefer the workbook (cell "B5") to auto update, so without having to run macro's or press buttons.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D16:E25")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please edit one cell at a time!"
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        newVal = Target.Value
        Range("D16:E25").ClearContents
        Target.Value = newVal
        a = ActiveCell

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If

If a.Column = 4 Then
    Range("B5") = Range(a).Offset(0, -2).Value
        Else: Range("B5") = Range(a).Offset(0, -3).Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you admonish the use of a multiple cell edit with a MsgBox but do not reverse the process (thereby allowing the multiple cell edit to remain)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up `a` as a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) may be a little overkill since you already have the row by looking at the single cell target.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D16:E25")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Intersect(Target, Range("D16:E25")).Cells.Count > 1 Then
            Application.Undo
            MsgBox "Please edit one cell at a time!"
        Else
            Dim newVal As Variant

            newVal = Target.Value
            Range("D16:E25").ClearContents
            Target.Value = newVal
            Cells(5, 2) = Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value

        End If
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad that worked out for you. Note that I included a call to `Application.Undo` to reverse multiple cell edits within the D16:E25 range.

Answer (score 2):

3 Issues here:
Firstly if a is set as a Range then the correct way to do it would be

```
Set a = ActiveCell
```

Secondly, if a is set as a Range, the correct way to call it in the second if function would be

```
If a.Column = 4 Then
    Range("B5") = a.Offset(0, -2).Value
       Else: Range("B5") = a.Offset(0, -3).Value
End If
```

instead of

```
If a.Column = 4 Then
    Range("B5") = Range(a).Offset(0, -2).Value
       Else: Range("B5") = Range(a).Offset(0, -3).Value
End If
```

and thirdly the above if function should be placed between

```
Set a = ActiveCell
```

and

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

then your program will be run as intended when the intersect is true.

Comment: If `a` was indeed a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), then it should be `Set`, not simply assigned.

Comment: yea agreed.. but the use of "a.column" makes it seem like the intention was for it to be a range rather than a string

Comment: yup noticed that there were the other 2 issues..thx for pointing that out